# Python: how to utilize instances of a class

Tags: python, database, class, filter, data-processing

*New to OOP and python*, I am *struggling enormously* to grasp what good *classes actually are for*. I tried to ask *help from a lecturer* who said "oh, then you should read about general methods to classes". *Been putting in a days work but get no where*.

I get it that a class allow you to collect an instance structure and methods to it, like this:

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, item_id, item_name):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item_name = item_name
    def show_list(self):
        print(self.item_id, self.item_name)
idA = Items("idA", "A")
idA.show_list()
```

**But what is even the point** of a class if there were not MANY instances you would classify? If I have a method within the class, I must hard code the actual instance to call the class for. What if you want a user to search and select an instance, to then do operations to (e.g. print, compute or whatever)??

I thought of doing it like this:

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, item_id, item_name):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item_name = item_name
    def show_list(self):
        print(self.item_id, self.item_name)
idA = Items("idA", "A")
idB = Items("idB", "B")
select_item = input("enter item id")
select_item.show_list()
```

Replacing hard coded variable with input variable doesn't work, probably logically. I then played with the idea of doing it like this:

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, item_id, item_name):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item_name = item_name
iL = [Items('idA', 'A'), Items('idB', 'B')]
selected_item = input("enter item id")
for selected_item in iL:
    print(f'{selected_item.item_id} {selected_item.item_name}')
```

Now all are called thanks to making it a list instead of separate instances, but how do I actually apply code to filter and only use one instance in the list (dynamically, based on input)?

I would love the one who brought me sense to classes. You guys who work interactively with large data sets must do something what I today believe exist in another dimension.

See examples above^^

Comment: `...brought me sense to classes.` - that is a very broad topic and not a good fit for SO.  Sometimes using a class makes sense, sometimes it doesn't. Using or not using classes can just be a personal preference or coding style.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to find all the instances of a certain element within a class.

This is as simple as:

```
print([x for x in iL if x.item_id == selected_item])
```

Now, you may ask why you can't just store the elements of `iL` as tuples instead of classes. The answer is, you can, but

```
("idA", "A")
```

is much less descriptive than:

```
item_id = "idA"
item_name = "A"
```

Any code you write with classes, you should in theory be able to write without classes. Classes are for the benefit of the coder, not the end-user of the program. They serve to make the program more readable, which I'm sure you'll find is a desirable property.

Answer (score 0):

Your point here is to lookup for `Items` instances based on their `item_id` attribute.

That's a thing to create instances of a class.

It's a completely different thing to search for items objects stored in memory - that is not directly linked to the concept of OOP, classes and instances.

You could use dictionary to store references of your objects and then lookup in your dictionary.

```py
class Items:
    def __init__(self, item_id, item_name):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.item_name = item_name
    def show_list(self):
        print(self.item_id, self.item_name)

idA = Items("idA", "A")
idB = Items("idB", "B")
lookup_dict = {"idA": idA, "idB": idB}
select_item = input("enter item id")
found_item = lookup_dict.get(select_item)
if found_item:
    found_item.show_list()
else:
    print(f"item {select_item} not found")
```